# How to make a closure function choose between 2 outer functions that need to be called?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop and I want to pass a function (with a parameter) that will call ONLY one of my two outer functions (depends on the value of parameter I pass). How can I specify which function to call WITHOUT USING IF/ELSE.

So far I have the code working with both outer functions (accessOne & accessTwo); however, I want ONLY ONE of the functions to be run depending on the value of the parameter 'color' (again, I could use if/else, but for some reasons I do NOT want to use it). You will notice that I didn't use the parameter 'color', I mean, I did use it but it's not really functioning (it's useless), but I put it just to show you how it's supposed to be, I think.

// main function

```
mainFunction(color){
...
for(i=0 ; i<object.length ; k++){

    const f = (color) => {
            accessOne(object[i]);

            accessTwo(object[i]);
        }

f(color);
}
```

//Outer functions

```
function accessOne(objectElement) {
    objectElement.style['background-color']= '#FFFF00';
}

function accessTwo(objectElement) {
    objectElement.style['background-color']= '#48D1CC';
}
```

I expect to get all object elements to be Yellow id the color entered was yellow, or all of them to be blue if the color entered is blue, for example. So, the function "f" should know which function to choose/to call depending on the input parameter.

Comment: Why not just make one function that accepts the color and then set the background-color to that? I don't understand your logic for making a new function for each color.

Comment: *How* do you decide which function to call based on the colour?

Comment: @RyanWilson because I might have additional statements (which might be different) in each function. For example, adding console.log("12345") in one function and console.log("6789") in the other one, so I d need to differentiate them!

Comment: @Hassan In that case you can just pass the log value as a paremeter to the method, and you can still use one function.

Comment: @VLAZ that's exactly my question.

Comment: No, I'm asking what is the relationship between the value of `color` and the function to be called? First of all, what even is `color` - hex value, HSL value, an English word, an object, or what? And how would the value influence the choice - do you want `"purple"` to call `accessOne` but everything `accessTwo`? Do you want to count the number of vowels in the word and base the decision on that? Do you want to base it on the levels of red present in the colour? What about the luminescence levels? It's completely unclear how you want to make that choice so I can't even do it with an `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a conditional operator and the *outer functions* are publicly accessible you can use:

```
const f = (color) => {
    window[color == "yellow" ? "accessOne" : "accessTwo"](object[i]);
}
```

**Note:** There is probably a better way to set the background colour of an element than the way you're trying to use.

---

If you are able to rename the outer functions to something like `set_yellow` and `set_blue` you can use the following instead:

```
const f = (color) => {
    window["set_" + color](object[i]);
}
```

Comment: hope I could do it like that, but I'm not supposed to use any conditional statements (conditional operator, if/else, switch..)

Comment: Can you rename the outer functions?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide an alternative, if that helps.

Comment: wow finally it works! yeah I renamed the outer functions and I used your code. THANKS a lot really appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help @Hassan 